# How can I animate an attribute value (not style property) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe, animation

I need to animate the height attribute of iframe, but seems like the animate function accepts style properties only. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iframe height attribute and CSS height attribute applied to an iframe act the same way. So just set the height in css rather than as an attribute.